# Insert line after div's grandparent

Tags: javascript

`this` corresponds to a specific div.

I would like to insert a piece of code after its grandparent using this code but it doesn't seem to work: `this.parentNode[0].parentNode[0].insertAfter(newrespondform);`

I can provide more code if needed but after trying to debug I'm pretty ure the problem lie in here.
How could I write it so that it works? I cannot add an ID to the grandparent to select it that way.

Thanks for your aid :)

EDIT - here is the entire code that gets loaded on page load:

```
function comrespond(){
    function addresform(){
    var resid = this.getAttribute('id'),
    grandParent = this.parentNode.parentNode,
    newrespondform = '<div class="commentresponse"><span></span><span><p class="author">Leave a reply:</p><form id="commentform" action="http://split.snippetspace.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" onsubmit="addcomment(); return false;"><input id="author" aria-required="true" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/><input id="email" aria-required="true" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email address" /><textarea id="comment" aria-required="true" name="comment" rows="8"></textarea><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post Comment" /><input id="comment_post_ID" name="comment_post_ID" type="hidden" value="'+resid+'" /></form></span></div>';
    grandParent.parentNode.insertBefore(newrespondform, grandParent.nextSibling);
    }
    var responsebtn = document.getElementsByClassName('comment-reply-link');
    for(var i = 0; i < responsebtn.length; i++){
                    bindEvt(responsebtn[i], "click", addresform);
                };}
```

the HTML:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span>
        <p class="author">Christopher</p>
        <div class="comment-reply-link" id="106"></div>
        <p>test comment 2 to see if it increments!</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: An element can only have a single parent element, so `parentNode` is never an array. Also there is no `insertAfter()` function. There is a `insertBefore()` which expects two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

First, property `parentNode` contains a single node only, not a set of nodes, hence you don't need to apply `[0]` to get the first node. Next, there is no `insertAfter` method in native JavaScript. Instead you may use a trick with `insertBefore`. So the solution might look like that:

```
var grandParent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
grandParent.parentNode.insertBefore(newrespondform, grandParent.nextSibling);
```

Comment: this looks good, however in IE10 that last line triggers 'SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.'. Cannot try on other browsers right now but probably the same. Any ideas? thanks for your help!

Comment: @SnippetSpace It should work fine. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/GFeFR/.

Comment: alright, there must be something wrong somewhere else. I've added the full code to the original post, could you maybe take a look at it? sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`parentNode`is not an array, so just getting rid of the `[0]` should do it I think.

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.insertAfter(newrespondform);
```